# ¿Puedo servir una pagina web directamente con python y django en un VPS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, seguridad, nginx

He visto que todo el mundo sirve las paginas web con un NGINX o APACHE en vez de servir la aplicación directamente con DJANGO, sin embargo no encuentro las vulnerabilidades que podrían aplicar a ataques si sirves directamente la web con este Framework en el puerto 80 ya que todas las documentaciones oficiales aplican a este tipo de servidor web. Si montamos una aplicacion django con uWSGI y NGINX quedaria de esta forma:

- the web client <-> the web server <-> the socket <-> uWSGI <-> Python

Entiendo que sino saltamos esto:

- the web client <-> the socket <-> Python

Parece ser que con este último formato perderíamos muchos logs o trazas que nos interesan pero ¿existen vulnerabilidades sobre ello?

Comment: cuando publicas con apache igual estas usando django la diferencia es con WSGI, el log que te arroja django al condigurarlo en tu virtualhost te lo guarda en un archivo y ese lo puedes ver

Comment: Tanto NGINX como Apache están inactivos, en principio solamente estoy usando el servidor de desarrollo de django "python3 manage.py runserver 0:80". Están haciendo muchos ataques de tipo "Propfind" los cuales no consiguen nada (son webdav para microsoft IIS) y algunos "GET /current_config/passwd HTTP/1.1"  con lo que tampoco están haciendo nada. La dejaré más tiempo a modo honeypot para comprobar si hay alguien que pueda saltarse alguna barrera con este framework. El runserver del manage.py realmente utiliza el comando django-admin y utiliza WSGI.

Comment: En la propia documentación DJANGO especifican no usar este servidor para producción pero también comentan que simplemente no ha pasado por auditorias de seguridad, no que no sea seguro (de momento... como todo)